# Use Dagger generated test code in Android

Tags: android, android-testing, dagger-2

I'm trying to use [Dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) in my android project as explained in [hitherejoe/Android-Boilerplate](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Android-Boilerplate). While I am setting up the project I got following error on build time.

```
Error:(30, 26) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerTestComponent
```

After digging into the documentation and generated code I figured out that code is not generating in debug (/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/) folder but in test/debug(/app/build/generated/source/apt/test/debug) folder. 
So in my test source folder can not import the generated DaggerTestComponent.

Any clue how to include test/debug folder to the source?
My dependancies are as follows

```
testCompile 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem? You should reference code generated in `test/debug` only from `test` folder. Please, provide more details. How you are trying to use generated code? Where the consumer of generated code is placed? Where generated code is placed? Provide simplified version of your code.

Comment: @MyDogTom I can not run the UI test as it need a Dagger Generated class which is in test/debug folder. I can not import that class as Android studio doesn't recognize it. Any idea how to include it?

Comment: What do you mean by UI tests? Instrumentation tests or jvm test with robolectric? In case of Instrumentation it's 'androidTest' folder and you need 'androidTestApt' for that + put your code int right folder + run `assembleAndroidTest`. Otherwise, hard to guess without details :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem... I worked around it by adding the generated test source directory:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        // add dagger generated files (works only with debug build)
        test.java.srcDirs += ['build/generated/source/apt/test/debug']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well for the issue. But I'm getting duplicate class issue. I'll post detailed error after digging in to it.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
// Dagger 2
provided "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
```

Comment: Thanks @Matias for the answer. Code is generating in test/debug folder which is not recognized by Android studio as a source folder. Any idea how to solve this?